# Ledger CLI automated transactions

Tags: automation, ledger-cli

Given a [ledger-cli](https://www.ledger-cli.org/3.0/doc/ledger3.html#Concrete-Example-of-Automated-Transactions) entry like

```
2017-11-30 * Terrace door ; :share:
    Expenses:Housing:Fixed                    719.06
    Assets:Bank:Checking Account
```

what would an automated transaction / transaction pattern match look like that

- identifies that the account Expenses:Housing:* is involved and
- the transaction uses the tag :share:  ?

Comment: That's a really obscure package.  Have you tried the Google Group?  (Look at the bottom of READMD.md.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just combine both conditions with `&`

```
= /Expenses:Housing:/ & tag("share")
```

But also make sure you have two or more spaces before your tag comment:

```
2017-11-30 * Terrace door       ; :share:
    Expenses:Housing:Fixed                    719.06
    Assets:Bank:Checking Account
```